# WebPageTest :: How can Start Render be after the load event?

Tags: web-performance, webpagetest

What can cause the start render to be delayed even after the load event has fired?

Look at this [webpagetest result](http://www.webpagetest.org/result/160608_0V_c5a667900a219ebfda3824a276dcc953/1/details/) 
[image: See screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is most probably a bug. For the moment, the iPhone instance on WebPageTest is quite recent and the author is still improving it:

> The iOS support is just becoming stable though it's still under VERY active development so don't be surprised if there are a few rough edges (and a lot more limitations than the android testing).
>   *- Patrick Meenan, 09-09-2015*

The android tests are much more reliable.

Answer (score 1):

If you check the page you tested without javascript (F1 > Disable Javascript in Chrome DevTools), you can see that most images are lazy-loaded, which mean they are loaded via a [JS script checking if the images are in the viewport](http://developer.telerik.com/featured/lazy-loading-images-on-the-web/). As you can see, without JS the load time line is well after all assets loaded.

Also for other assets, like JS, you can add an [`async` or `defer` attribute](https://davidwalsh.name/html5-async) to de-synchronize your scripts loads.

Finally, some scripts can be even deliberately loaded after the load event using an attachment on the window `load` event to write `<script>` tags in the body when it's triggered as [loadJS](https://github.com/filamentgroup/loadJS) do for example.

You should [read that](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/?hl=en) by the way to better understand how rendering and events timing work.

[image: No-javascript load]